# How to set accessory view background to same background as content view in UItableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uitableview

I've successfully changed the background of table view cells to an image in my app but it does not extend to the background of the accessory view. Any idea to fix this ?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Comment: A screenshot would be very helpful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-Cell-Image.jpg"]];
```

try this way if you are using text label of the cell only to display content

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` delegate function of tableview. Give background color to the cell in that function. It will give the color to accessary view background also.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, that I found most helpful. What worked for me though, was to set the cell color in IB (the cell was a prototype):

[image]